# ¿Qué puede generar problemas en la comunicación de la base de datos con el host?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web, hosting

Hay una página web la cual ya funcionaba relativamente bien, la cual hace unas semanas dejo de funcionar sin motivo aparente. No puedo hacer inserciones ni updates en la base de datos(código de error 2053). Abriendo tickets en el hosting(hostpapa) me comentan que hubo una actualización del php a la version 7, lo cual nos da a entender que esos errores empezaron desde esta dicha actualización. Viendo los snapshots algunas veces marca algunos errores:

```
- 60141     /usr/sbin/httpd -k start    0%  280
- 89274     lsphp   0%  5
- 89545     lsphp:/home/mundo290/public_html/api/index.php  0%  6
- 89546     convert /home/mundo290/public_html/api/cache/18739706_182289292299257_6025755164033647748_n.jpg -thumbnail 250x250 -background white -gravity center -extent 250x250 /home/mundo290/public_html/public/img/eventos/8/1t1496329568.jpg   0%  1...
```

Y también marca que mysql se duerme hasta 20 segundos. También les comento que a veces sí permite hacer los INSERT y los UPDATES.

Comment: suena a problema del hosting.. tal vez tocaron algo en el update??

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No, en el codigo no hemos hecho modificaciones, hacemos pruebas locales y el codigo funciona bien, pero en el host la base de datos no funciona, muchas veces hacemos los cambios y nos sale el aviso de que se hizo el cambio pero en la base de datos no aparencen los cambios, :( no se si deba volver a subir nuevamente todo el codigo a ver si funciona.

Comment: Puede ser un problema de versiones de PHP? Para que versión era originalmente la app? Puedes poner algo de codigo?

Comment: la version funciona para 5.6 no deberia fallar, la comunicacion con la base de datos es con PDO

Answer (score 0):

Con PHP 7 se introdujeron *bastantes* cambios a nivel de funciones de bases de datos. Seguramente tu código utilizará alguna función que ha sido modificada o eliminada en dicha actualización y por lo tanto no funciona.

Revisa el log de errores del servidor web para ver exactamente en que línea del código php está el error.

Si no puedes ver el log de errores del servidor mediante el panel de control de tu hosting siempre puedes añadir este código al principio de tu PHP, lanzar la página con el navegador y luego abrir el fichero log_errores.log con el mismo navegador o mediante FTP.

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "log_errores.log");
```